# VMWare filesystem

Tags: virtualization, virtual-machine

I have VMWare virtual machine with an OS and I want to put some files in a folder on my physical machine to be able to access them from the virtual machine.

How can i do it? I. e. how can I share files between physical and virtual machines (as simple as possible)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to enable the shared folder. check [this](http://www.vmware.com/support/ws5/doc/ws_running_shared_folders.html) out